# How to solve this error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined)?

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, datatables

How can i solve this problem, this is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>       
    $(function() {
        $('#pemohon-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: 'http://localhost:8000/pemohon/get_datatable'
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table id="pemohon-table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>No</tr>
            <tr>Nomor Permohonan</tr>
            <tr>Tanggal Permohonan</tr>
            <tr>Nama</tr>
            <tr>Tanggal Lahir</tr>
            <tr>Status</tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
    </body>
```

And i got this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

I don't know what is the problem exactly, help me please. Thanks.

Comment: Your server side script might have been returning an error. Check your logs

Comment: Can you post whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use datatable maybe you can set like this:

in controller you make getData function

```
public function getData(Request $request){
    $pemohon = YourModel::select('your_coloum_in_database.*');
    return Datatables::of($pemohon)
                    ->make(true);
}
```

in you view you can call like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped w100" cellspacing="0" id="datatable"></table>

    <script>


$('#datatable').dataTable({
                        processing: true,
                        serverSide: true,
                        ajax: {
                            method: 'POST',
                            url : '{{ route('your_route') }}',
                            headers: {
                                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                            }
                        },
                        columns : [
                            {title: 'No', data: 'no, name: 'no', defaultContent: '-', class: 'text-center'},
                            {title: 'Nomor Permohonan', data: 'nomor_permohonan', name: 'nomor_permohonan', defaultContent: '-', class: 'text-center'},
                            {title: 'Tanggal Permohonan', data: 'tanggal_permohonan', name: 'tanggal_permohonan', defaultContent: '-', class: 'text-center'},
                            {title: 'Nama', data: 'nama', name: 'nama', defaultContent: '-', class: 'text-center'},
                            {title: 'Tanggal Lahir', data: 'tanggal_lahir', name: 'tanggal_lahir', defaultContent: '-', class: 'text-center'},{title: 'Status', data: 'status', name: 'status', defaultContent: '-', class: 'text-center'},
    </script>
```